# ArgumentError in 'sessions_helper#remember' [Ruby 2.2.0, Rails 4.2.0]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I started a new application using Michael Hartl tutorial. Everything is working fine, except when I mark a 'remember' checkbox (that uses method remember in class sessions_helper), or use the remember method. The error says that I'm passing 2 arguments instead of 1, but this is weird, since I'm passing only one (user).

The error:

```
       (463.7ms)  commit transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 684ms

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
  app/models/user.rb:44:in `remember'
  app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:30:in `remember'
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

The remember method:

```
  /app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb
  def remember user
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end




  /app/models/user.rb     
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attributes(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end
```

And, the sessions controller that calls the create/new method/action:

```
  /app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Wrong Login/password combination"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

And, the form for sign_in:

```
/app/views/sessions/new.html.erb
    <%= form_for(:session, url: signin_path) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me, class: "checkbox inline" do %>
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
        <span>Remember me on this computer</span>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.submit "Sign In!", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably the update_attributes method in your User#remember method that is causing the error. You are passing two parameters to update_attributes, but update_attributes accepts only one argument.

Change `update_attributes(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))` to `update_attributes({remember_digest: User.digest(remember_token)})`. (You can omit `{}` when you pass a hash to a method as the last argument, but I added them to emphasize that the updated version passes only one parameter to the method.

`app/models/user.rb:44:in 'remember'` means that the error occurred inside the User#remember method. If an error occurs because you are passing wrong numbers of arguments to User#remember method, then the error message probably says that the error occurred where you call the remember method. In your case, `params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)`.

Comment: FINALLY! Worked like a charm, thanks! Also, this is really weird: I checked again the book and no one did a question about this (in the book the method is exactly how I said in the first post). Also I had in my mind that the error was in 'sessions_helper#remember' because when I edited the method the error disappeared. I can't upvote your answer, but thanks man, made my day.